# Get credit card type for custom form using braintree

Tags: javascript, jquery, braintree

In my from card number field, on key up i want to show the card type with icon.

For that im using braintree.. see below code

```
braintree.setup(clientToken, "custom", {
  id: "checkout",
  onPaymentMethodReceived: function(obj){
    console.log(obj.details.cardType);
  }
});
```

With the above code im getting the credit card type on submit, how can i make it to happen on key up...

Thanks

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://codebeautify.org/credit-card-validate).

Card types and their format is provided which wil make it easier for you to create `regex`.

Use the following tools to build and test `regex`.

- [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)
- [http://regexr.com](http://regexr.com/)